# Styling a scroll picker

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to style the scrolling picker (just what's the correct word for this would help) for a website on iOS Safari. I know that this is possible because they do it on the geico.com form (second page of this form: https://sales2.geico.com/) - but I can't figure out how they did it!

Here's a picture of the request:
[image]

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I did use https://mobiscroll.com/ in a previous project to achieve this, also available from https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll if you like to fiddle around a bit by yourself.